# Appropriate similarity metrics for multiple sets of 2D coordinates

Tags: algorithm, 2d, coordinates, similarity

I have a collection of 2D coordinate sets (on the scale of a 100K-500K points in each set) and I am looking for the most efficient way to measure the similarity of 1 set to the other. I know of the usuals: Cosine, Jaccard/Tanimoto, etc.  However I am hoping for some suggestions on any fast/efficient ones to measure similarity, especially ones that can cluster by similarity.

Edit 1: The image shows what I need to do. I need to cluster all the reds, blues and greens by their shape/orientatoin, etc.

[alt text http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/8121/curves.png](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/8121/curves.png)

Comment: Could you further define similarity?  From my understanding, you have n sets of m points (where m is on the order of 100k).  What criteria would you use to say that any 2 sets are similar?  Would it be that they share a large subset of identical points (i.e., identical x,y coordinates) or that the sets of coordinates in the two sets superimpose closely (i.e., different coordinates that describe geometrically similar 2-d objects).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking more at the latter i.e. they describe similar 2D objects. Let me explain my use-case a bit, I have multiple rapidly changing  scatter-plots and would like to cluster them by similarity. HTH and TIA

Comment: Would a cross-correlation help? However I am confused how to make it size invariant. Could I normalize by the number of co-ordinates?

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Why are the greens (or the reds) similar?  They are mirror images of each other.  Accounting for that will add complexity to any algorithm that you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first step of any solution is going to be to find the centroid, or other reference point, of each shape, so that they can be compared regardless of absolute position.

One algorithm that comes to mind would be to start at the point nearest the centroid and walk to its nearest neighbors.  Compare the offsets of those neighbors (from the centroid) between the sets being compared.  Keep walking to the next-nearest neighbors of the centroid, or the nearest not-already-compared neighbors of the ones previously compared, and keep track of the aggregate difference (perhaps RMS?) between the two shapes.  Also, at each step of this process calculate the rotational offset that would bring the two shapes into closest alignment [and whether mirroring affects it as well?].  When you are finished you will have three values for every pair of sets, including their direct similarity, their relative rotational offset (mostly only useful if they are close matches after rotation), and their similarity after rotation.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but your response got me started in a good direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try K-means algorithm. It dynamically calculated the centroid of each cluster and calculates distance to all the pointers and associates them to the nearest cluster.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately k-means does not appear to be well suited since n is not known a-priori.

Answer (score 0):

Since your clustering is based on a nearness-to-shape metric, perhaps you need some form of connected component labeling.  UNION-FIND can give you a fast basic set primitive.

For union-only, start every point in a different set, and merge them if they meet some criterion of nearness, influenced by local colinearity since that seems important to you.  Then keep merging until you pass some over-threshold condition for how difficult your merge is.  If you treat it like line-growing (only join things at their ends) then some data structures become simpler.  Are all your clusters open lines and curves?  No closed curves, like circles?

The crossing lines are trickier to get right, you either have to find some way merge then split, or you set your merge criteria to extremely favor colinearity and you luck out on the crossing lines.