# Comparing sets of 2D data/scatterplots

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graphics, cluster-analysis, similarity

I have 2000 sets of data which contain little over 1000 2D variables each. I'm looking to cluster these sets of data into anywhere from 20-100 clusters based on similarity. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a reliable method of comparing sets of data. I've tried a few (rather primitive) approaches and done loads of research, but I can't seem to find anything that fits what I need to do.

I've posted an image below of 3 sets of my data plotted. The data is bounded 0-1 in the y axis, and is within the ~0-0.10 range in the x axis (in practice, but could be greater then 0.10 in theory).

The shape and relative proportions of the data are probably the most important things to compare. However, the absolute locations of each data set are important as well. In other words, the closer the relative position of each individual point to the individual points of another dataset, the more similar they would be and then their absolute positions would need to be accounted for.

Green and red should be considered as very different, but push comes to shove, they should be more similar than blue and red.

[image: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/6730/screenshot20110204at004.png]

I have tried to:

- compare based on overall overages and deviation
- split the variables into coordinate regions (ie (0-0.10, 0-0.10), (0.10-0.20, 0.10-0.20)...(0.9-1.0, 0.9-1.0)) and compare similarity based on shared points within regions
- I've tried measuring the average euclidean distance to nearest neighbours among the data sets

All of these have produced faulty results. The closest answer I could find in my research was "[Appropriate similarity metrics for multiple sets of 2D coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101467)". However, the answer given there suggests comparing the average distance among nearest neighbours from the centroid, which I don't think will work for me as the direction, is as important as the distance for my purposes.

I might add, that this will be used to generate data for the input of another program and will only be used sporadically (mainly to generate different sets of data with different numbers of clusters), so semi time consuming algorithms are not out of the question.

Comment: Agree to Joe Blow - you could try to do a linear fit with least squares method to get 3 line equations for green,blue,red dots and compare slope and intercept for these three equations.

Comment: Also you could try to compare Hausdorff distance between clusters.

Comment: Do all datasets have the same number of points?  Are the order of the points significant (Does point #5 have a similar meaning for all datasets?)

Comment: No, there's no special meaning for any given point index. @Joe Blow I'm exploring line fitting with LOESS and looking into comparing the lines as part of the comparison, thanks. @belisarius, thanks. I'll be sure to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**In two steps**

1) First: To tell apart blues.

Compute the mean nearest neighbor distance, up to a cutoff. Select the cutoff something like the black distance in the following image:

[image]

The blue configurations, as they are more scattered will give you results much greater than the reds and greens.

2) Second: To tell apart reds and greens

Disregard all points whose nearest neighbor distance is more than something smaller (for example one fourth of the previous distance). Clusterize for proximity so to get clusters of the form:

[image] and [image]

Discard the clusters with less than 10 points (or so). For each cluster run a linear fit and calculate covariances. The mean covariance for red will be much higher than for green since greens are very aligned in this scale.

There you are.

HTH!

Comment: At the very least, I imagine calculating the average distance to x nearest neighbours will be far better than my average nearest distance to the nearest neighbour. I haven't had a chance to experiment with it yet, but i suspect it will make a good metric paired with some others. I'm not sure about the second part, but I'll have a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @mcnulty I did things like this one many times (as a physicist). You have to experiment with the cutoff values. If all your reds, greens and blues are similar to those posted, you'll not find many troubles. Of course expect a lot of cpu time ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Although belisarius has answered this well, here are a couple of comments:

if you could reduce each set of 1000 points to say 32 clusters of 32 points each
(or 20 x 50 or ...), then you could work in 32-space instead of 1000-space.
Try [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) for this;
see also
[SO questions/tagged/k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k-means).

One way to measure distance between sets A, B (of points, of clusters)
is to take nearest pairs like this:

```
def nearestpairsdistance( A, B ):
    """ large point sets A, B -> nearest b each a, nearest a each b """
        # using KDTree, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html
    Atree = KDTree( A )
    Btree = KDTree( B )
    a_nearestb, ixab = Btree.query( A, k=1, p=p, eps=eps )  # p=inf is fast
    b_nearesta, ixba = Atree.query( B, k=1, p=p, eps=eps )
    if verbose:
        print "a_nearestb:", nu.quantiles5(a_nearestb)
        print "b_nearesta:", nu.quantiles5(b_nearesta)
    return (np.median(a_nearestb) + np.median(b_nearesta)) / 2
        # means are sensitive to outliers; fast approx median ?
```

You *could* then cluster your 2000 points in 32-space to 20 cluster centres
in one shot:

```
centres, labels = kmeans( points, k=20, iter=3, distance=nearestpairsdistance )
```

(the usual Euclidean distance wouldn't work here at all.)

Please follow-up — tell us what worked in the end, and what didn't.